# Is there no way to create a folder in Spotify using the web API? Is there a way creating a PC app instead?

Tags: api, directory, spotify, creation

I have scoured the internet, and at this point is there anything remotely programmatic that will create a folder?

Answer (score 1):

Not using the Web API, no.

However, libspotify has an API for creating folders: `sp_playlistcontainer_add_folder()`. This isn't a Web API - you'll need to write a native application.

Comment: That is to bad, I wanted to be able to do what I want to do inside spotify, not create an external thing.  This might be a stupid question but I have C# installed on my computer, that should be fine for writing this right?

Comment: There are a couple of C# wrappers for libspotify - have a Google and you'll find them.